# Object keys js react problem with array name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I display the name of my array in my div? (I want to display the 19)

Thank you

```
{19: {…}, 22: {…}, 24: {…}}
19: {libelle: "testall", stat: Array(4)}
22: {libelle: "test2", stat: Array(4)}
24: {libelle: "test3", stat: Array(4)}
__proto__: Object

 {Object.keys(mydata).map((info, index) => (
 <div>
    {console.log(mydata)}
 </div>
 ))}
```

Comment: have you tried displaying `index` ?

Comment: index sends me : 0,1,2

Comment: `console.log(info)` should do it

Comment: thank, its okay with info, my bad :o